# Is it possible to use svg images with Overleaf

Tags: svg, overleaf

Unfortunately I am not able to include svg images in overleaf. This is the minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{svg}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \centering
  \includesvg{image.svg}
  \caption{svg image}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

This will give an error says

```
File `./image' not found
```

Overleaf does allow svg extensions but how can I include the file?

Comment: The `svg` package requires the shell escape to be enabled and an existing installation of Inkscape - which probably is not available on Overleaf. Converting the SVG files to PDF using Inkscape manually before and uploading this PDF files could be a possible workaround.

Comment: Just to add on to @epR8GaYuh's comment, shell escape is enabled on Overleaf, but Inkscape isn't available on the servers for now.

Comment: I have tried with 2022 Overleaf, with svg generated from a google slide. It works fine. Thanks

Answer (score 65, accepted):

This does work on <s>the</s> Overleaf v2 <s>beta</s>, where Inkscape's available. [Here](https://www.overleaf.com/read/cggssskyjwqw)'s the MWE above on the <s>beta</s> new version of the site:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{svg}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\title{Inkscape package on Overleaf }
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \centering
  \includesvg{image.svg}
  \caption{svg image}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: MWE not found - is this really possible?

Comment: Oops, apologies - I'd accidentally deleted the example. I've recreated it and updated the link.

Comment: I added the code and a screenshot because external links are very likely to be broken in the (maybe not near) future. The screenshot is not in a really good quality - you can replace it with another if you want, and feel free to roll back if you don't like :)

Comment: @walszje thanks for the example. It worked for me however my svg doesn't fit into a single  column. How can I fix it ? Actually, I can fit into a single column by `\includesvg[width=\columnwidth]` but it becomes unreadable.

Comment: It does not work now, can not figure out the reason

Comment: @Travis it works now

Comment: @zwlayer Try `\begin{figure} \centering \def\svgwidth{\columnwidth} \includesvg{image} \end{figure}` or consult [this document](http://tug.ctan.org/info/svg-inkscape/InkscapePDFLaTeX.pdf)

Comment: Just a heads-up: if your SVG has Unicode text, it wont work as PDFlatex doesn't support all Unicode. Whereas, PDF carries the necessary Unicode fonts within it.  
So unicode people, prefer PDF over SVG inside latex.

Comment: The linked project doesn't seem to work right now on overleaf.

Comment: I updated the file so it works again, albeit with a different image. Sorry about that issue, I made the project while I worked at Overleaf, seems it was updated by someone there in between times