# SVG Figure in Latex Overleaf

Tags: overleaf, svg, inkscape

I am struggling to import a `figure.SVG` in Overleaf.

I tried with

```
\usepackage{svg}
```

but it doesn't work.

I read a few times about Inkscape, however I work on Overleaf and I have no idea how to install `Inkscape`. Could someone give me some instructions.

Thanks

I try to reformulate my question.

I draw a diagram on draw.io and inserted also some math-notations (Q_dot and subscripts). If I export the file as a `.svg` and inport it in my latex document the Math notations are gone! See on the screenshot

[image]

On top of that do I get the error "Viewer does not support full SVG 1.1"

Is there a way to import `.svg`files without getting any losses in the math notation?
I tried also to convert the `.svg`into a `.pdf`however do I get the same problem.
how are figures with Math notations normally imported into a LaTeX file?

Comment: what does "does not work" mean? If you get an error show the error message, all the required tools are available pre-installed see https://www.overleaf.com/read/cggssskyjwqw

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to use svg images with Overleaf](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/442077/is-it-possible-to-use-svg-images-with-overleaf)

Comment: This seems to be a problem with the `svg` file rather than with Overleaf. Try this: Download it, open it in [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/) and check if (a) the "text" in the drawing is really text (and not paths) and (b) the "Viewer does not support full SVG 1.1" is there, too.

Comment: If I open it on Inkscape I get it in the same format as the screenshot I have postet. :/ should I try another software to draw such diagrams? any suggestions?