# Horizontal lines in SVG are not rendered

Tags: graphics, svg

I'm trying to include a SVG image in a TeX document (on Overleaf, if that matters). Here's the image: https://svgshare.com/s/rcv (created using Inkscape, the LaTeX is from TeXText)

The horizontal lines render correctly in Inkscape / Chrome / Firefox / whatever other viewer I tried, but here's how it looks like when included in a TeX document:

[image: diagram]

Minimal reproducible example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{svg}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includesvg[width=\textwidth]{test_prod.svg}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

where "test_prod.svg" is the above svg file. I'm compiling using pdfLaTeX but XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX give the same output. Any suggestions? This is driving me mad...

Comment: The `svg` package converts the svg to PDF. For that you need `--shell-escape` and Inkscape if you use it locally. It should also work on overleaf, see [Is it possible to use svg images with Overleaf](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/442077/123129). Alternatively you could try to create this graphic inside latex, e.g. with tikz.

Comment: Since this is in fact an Inkscape issue, I vote to close as off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at the PDF file output by Inkscape. You can clearly see, that the lines are already missing, so this is not related to package `svg` and would rather be an [Inkscape (export) issue](https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inkscape/-/issues). I also tried to add some elements to your original SVG file and these weren't output to the exported PDF file either.

I did not investigate further to find the reason for it. However, I could solve the issue by just copy and pasting the provided content to a new SVG file. Maybe, this helps you too.

Comment: I could even solve it by just re-setting the document size (`ctrl+shift+d`, Resize to content). Looking at the difference in the `svg` files, I can't really tell what the problem is though, so maybe a report to the issue tracker is still a good idea.